# matplotlib/python - How to draw a plot like this? mean ± 3*standard deviation

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want a picture like this:
[image]

The upper and lower limit of x axis is given and is much larger/smaller than the given data.

All plot I find is only  ± 1*standard deviation.

Also I am not sure how to fix the x axis like this.

My data is a python list of floats.

Right now, I only have three points, but  I would like to have line between them and vertical line at the points.
The x  axis is also not correct.

```
plt.figure()
x = []
for item in circ_list:
    x.append(float(item))
mean = np.mean(x)
std = np.std(x)
target_upper_bound = mean + 3 * std
target_lower_bound = mean - 3 * std

total_intermid = wear_limit[1] - wear_limit[0]
ten_percent_intermid = total_intermid / 10.0
plt.gca().axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.xlim([wear_limit[0],  wear_limit[1]])

plt.plot(x, np.zeros_like(x), 'x')
plt.plot(np.array([mean, mean + 2 * std, mean - 2 * std]),
         np.zeros_like(np.array([mean, mean + 2 * std, mean - 2 * std])), '|')

for i in x:
    plt.annotate(str(i), xy=(i, 0))
plt.annotate('mean', xy=(mean, 0))
plt.annotate('mean+3*std', xy=(target_upper_bound, 0))
plt.annotate('mean-3*std', xy=(target_lower_bound, 0))
plt.show()
```

Comment: can you provide some info on how your data looks and what you have tried?

Comment: I have added that @jlarsch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure I understand exactly what you are trying. Check out this example if it does something similar to what you want?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#create random data
data=np.random.random(100)
std=np.std(data)

#display the individual data points
plt.scatter(data,np.zeros(data.shape[0]))

#use errorbar function to create symmetric horizontal error bar 
#xerr provides error bar length
#fmt specifies plot icon for mean value
#ms= marker size
#mew = marker thickness
#capthick = thickness of error bar end caps
#capsize = size of those caps

plt.errorbar(np.mean(data),0,xerr=3*std,fmt='|', ms=30,mew=2,capthick=2,capsize=10)

#set x axis limits
plt.xlim([-10,10])
```

Comment: thanks. fmt='|'  seems not working, there is only a line(with no points or vertical lines) there.

Comment: also, how to show the minimum number and maxinum number of x axis on the graph(now there's only ticks)

Comment: now it's plotting individual data points, the mean and 3 * std. you can add the annotations to your points of interest?